# Add ASP DropDownList to li control dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've got the following code:

```
        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        ULRouting.Controls.Add(li);

        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        li.Attributes.Add("myCustomIDAtribute", "11");
        anchor.InnerText = "TabX";

        li.Controls.Add(anchor);
```

I'm trying to find out how you add a dropdown box to the li control when you dynamically create the li please ie:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbRoutingStage_1" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDBStages" DataTextField="stages" DataValueField="StageRefID"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "cmbRoutingStage_1";
ddl.DataSourceID = "sqlDBStages";
ddl.DataTextField = "stages";
ddl.DataValueField = "StageRefID";
li.Controls.Add(ddl);
```

As a side note you can use `HtmlAnchor` class for generating the anchor tag:-

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = new HtmlAnchor();
```